# Failing to upload JSON file through Chrome to Firebase Database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-console

This is really frustrating. I have a 104 MB JSON file that I want to upload to my Firebase database through the web front end, but after a random period of time (I've timed it, it's not constant, anywhere from 2 to 20 seconds) I get the error:

> There was a problem contacting the server. Try uploading your file again.

So I do try again, and it just keeps failing. I've uploaded files nearly this big before, and the limit for stored data in the realtime DB is 1 GB,

I'm not even close to that. Why does it keep failing to upload?

This is the error I get in chrome dev tools:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_ABORTED
https://project.firebaseio.com/.upload?auth=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6…Q3NiwiYWRtaW4iOnRydWUsInYiOjB9.CihvjvLSlx43nOBynAJeyibkBRtygeRlG4Yo1t3jKVA
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_ABORTED
```

If I click on the link that shows up in the error, it's a page with the words `POST request required`.

Comment: Are there any more detailed messages on the JavaScript console when the error occurs? Did you try splitting the file into multiple pieces and uploading those separately?

Comment: Yep, added error in console to OP. Splitting the file wouldn't work since each JSON file I upload overwrites existing data.

Comment: Have no luck import empty json {} too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the answer is to ignore the web importer entirely and use [firebase-import](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-import). It worked perfectly first time, and only took a minute to upload the whole json. And it also has merging capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

Using `firebase-import` as the accepted answer suggested, I get error:

```
Error: WRITE_TOO_BIG: Data to write exceeds the maximum size that can be modified with a single request.
```

However, with the [`firebase-cli`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli) I was successful in ***deleting my entire database***:

```
firebase database:remove /
```

It seems like it automatically traverses down your database tree to find requests that are under the limit size, then it does multiple delete requests automatically. It takes some time, but definitely works.

You can also import via a json file:

```
firebase database:set / data.json
```

I'm unsure if `firebase database:set` supports merging.